HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent in Error in Yii2 framework
I encounter an issue where my Yii2 project are giving below error on hosting. Running fine on local.
Fatal error: Uncaught yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: 
Headers already sent in/home8/nakkadka/public_html/amirulaina/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php on line 191.
in /home8/nakkadka/public_html/amirulaina/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:369 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home8/nakkadka/public_html/amirulaina/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(342): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders() 
#1 /home8/nakkadka/public_html/amirulaina/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(136): yii\web\Response->send() 
#2 /home8/nakkadka/public_html/amirulaina/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(323): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\ErrorException)) 
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError() 
#4 {main} thrown in /home8/nakkadka/public_html/amirulaina/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php
on line 369


I tried a few solutions that i found such as the examples below but im still stuck with this error. a weird behaviour is that when i reload the page its gone and once reload again, its there. so it goes back and forth between having that particular error and it being gone. I looked up this error and found 2 most talk about solution which is either not having an 'echo' in the controller or making sure there is no empty space before a php opening tag or after a php closing tag. Ive done both for all my files including double checking them and its still occurring. any insights would be greatly appreciated. As i am now unsure where to restart my debugging
Example 1
Example 2
Example 3
i also mainly read this post right here Thorough Solution since it gave a thorough explaination but it did not help. is it in some way  related to how yii2 renders some functions modifying the HTTP header?
Below is the view.php file which is a vendor file. THis is the function starting on line 181
public function endPage($ajaxMode = false)
{
    $this->trigger(self::EVENT_END_PAGE);

    $this->isPageEnded = true;

    $content = ob_get_clean();

    echo strtr($content, [
        self::PH_HEAD => $this->renderHeadHtml(),
        self::PH_BODY_BEGIN => $this->renderBodyBeginHtml(),
        self::PH_BODY_END => $this->renderBodyEndHtml($ajaxMode),
    ]);

    $this->clear();
}


what is the code in web/View.php on line 191?

@YourCommonSense that is a vendor file. I added it in the question


As i am now unsure where to restart my debugging

It looks like whatever triggers endPage() is too early for the part that wants to send headers on your remote system (but not locally).
This could be a configuration issue. Compare the size of the output buffer between both systems. If the remote one is lower than your local one, this could be a sign this is the case. Then make an educated guess and if you decide yourself this may be the culprit, change the remote configuration and test it.
If this did not help, restore the remote configuration. That is best if you can document the whole process so you have already captured that part of the configuration on both systems. Even if this was not the issue.
